# Removing Android Intent launcher and launch an app from a button in another app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to remove an app icon from the launcher and use the about button in a very simple memory game to launch the app. Do I have to change more than just the AnroidManifest?

This is the manifest for the game:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.8" package="com.mobilepearls.memory" platformBuildVersionCode="17" platformBuildVersionName="4.2.2-1425461">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MemoryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ListHighScoresActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" />
</manifest>
```

And this is the app I want to launch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="20" android:versionName="2.0" package="com.snsui.appHider" platformBuildVersionCode="14" platformBuildVersionName="4.0.1-202351">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".App">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SnsUIPasswordKeypadActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity-alias android:exported="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".SnsUIPwdFromKeyCode" android:targetActivity=".SnsUIPasswordKeypadActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".OldSnsUIPasswordKeypadActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
        <activity android:name=".XAppHiderActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
        <activity android:name=".SelectAppToHideActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" />
        <activity android:label="@string/menu_recommend" android:name="com.snsui.lib.recommend.RecommendActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="UMENG_APPKEY" android:value="52dd1f2356240b39fd02b114" />
        <meta-data android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL" android:value="Google" />
        <service android:name="com.umeng.common.net.DownloadingService" android:process=":DownloadingService" />
        <activity android:name="com.umeng.update.UpdateDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Add `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />`  just below the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intent filter that adds the an icon to the launcher:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```